# CSS is displayed wrong after deploying to Heroku

Tags: css, flask, heroku

I deployed a Flask app to Heroku and added domains and SSL. Now the CSS is displayed wrong. For example I made a red rating bar. Now it is displayed in blue. If I click "inspect element" it shows the correct CSS: background-color: red; but it is displayed in blue on the page! This is also true on different browsers: I tried Firefox, Opera, Safari and it's displayed wrongly everywhere. What is going wrong here? Did anyone else experience something like this?

How can I handle it to display my CSS correctly the way I wrote it?

EDIT: I figured it concerns only CSS that I used in the HTML style attribute. Only that is not displayed correctly. Any suggestions?

EDIT2: My Procfile just says: `web: gunicorn routes:app`

Also here is a picture of what I am talking about. Please disregard the green boxes. They just block name, address and phone number:[image]

Comment: You need to be more descriptive. Maybe show the actual web page. Show a comparison of the locally hosted web page and the one on Heroku. Maybe a link to your Heroku app.

Comment: checkout your procfile that is configured correctly and make sure your root address is correctly defined.

Comment: I added my Procfile and a screenshot above. Do you have more suggestions of what I can do?